# SQL find partial string match from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list string that is stored from user input. The input is open text which mean user can key in anything
Example of list is as follow:

1. MBPA-MCU-6520154 Error on registration at station no 5
2. Cannot find sensor no#412. Error code 87311264
3. Process on hold
4. Not able to continue. Msg: 135631

And I have a table of error codes:

| ErrorID | ErrorCode | Error Detail | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 312451 | Common error | No |
| 2 | 6520154 | Registration error | No |
| 3 | 87311264 | Sensor error | Yes |
| 4 | 135631 | Access denied | Yes |
| 5 | 1 | Next Error | Yes |

In this case item number 1 and 2 in the list match with code with 'Yes' status. I've been trying to create SQL query to get this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. An explanation of "match with code" would help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the free text that contains the `ErrorId`?  If so, this might be what you are looking for:

```
select ec.*
from error_codes ec
where @user_text like concat('%', ec.errorid, '%') and
      status = 'Yes';
```

If you want the longest match, you can use:

```
select top (1) ec.*
from error_codes ec
where @user_text like concat('%', ec.errorid, '%') and
      status = 'Yes'
order by ec.errorid desc;
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns 2 rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b1214/1

Comment: Both rows meet the condition of matching a number in the text.  Your question doesn't specify how the matching should occur.

Comment: It's worth noting that the wildcard matching will cause `'42'` to match `The Answer is 42.'`, `'(42)'`, `'Call BR-429 now.'`, `'4041424344'`... .